# Surface integrals and parametrisation and limits.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

This is a question in preparation for an exam I am going to sit. It is from a previous years exam and no solution has been provided.

Let S be the surface in R3 given by $$z = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2},x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$$
Let v be the vector field given by $${\bf F} = (z^2, z, y^2)$$
I wish to compute, without use of Stokes' theorem $\int_S(\nabla \times {\bf F}) \cdot d{\bf S}$ where dS is oriented inward toward the z axis.

Initially I thought about how to parametrise the cone and eventually settled with ${\bf p}(u, v) = (u, v, (u^2 + v^2)^{1/2})$ as I had seen similar in other examples.

Now I compute a vector which is perpendicular to the surface. $$\frac{\partial {\bf p}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial {\bf p}}{\partial v} = \left( \frac{-u}{(u^2 + v^2) ^ {1/2}}, \frac{-v}{(u^2 + v^2) ^ {1/2}}, 1 \right) $$
It is apparent that this vector points toward the z axis for all u and v.

I think the integral should be computed as follows, my issue is I am unsure what the limits should be.

$$\int_S(\nabla \times {\bf F}) \cdot d{\bf S} = \int_u\int_v (\nabla \times {\bf F})({\bf p}(u, v)) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial {\bf p}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial {\bf p}}{\partial v} \right) du dv$$

If you could help me to the final step of the calculation that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits of integration for $u,v$ need to be chosen in a way that together they paramerize the unit disk. A particular example would be $$-1 \leq u \leq1 \\ -\sqrt{1-u^2} \leq v \leq +\sqrt{1-u^2} .$$
The circular nature of this problem suggests using the more friendly parameterization of the surface $$\mathbf{p}(r,\theta)=(r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta,r) $$ by polar coordinates. This way, we have much simpler limits $$0 \leq r \leq 1 \\ 0\leq \theta\leq 2 \pi. $$